# Defining _POSIX_C_SOURCE as 2 causes error when changing code page on Windows CMD with MinGW GCC

Tags: c, cmd, mingw, codepages

I've been writing a Linux program that's meant to write non-English characters on the terminal, I've recently been porting it to Windows, and I've run into some issues, when trying to change the code page and the font of the terminal, having the symbolic constant _POSIX_C_SOURCE previously defined seems to change the behavior of the code, and makes it incapable of properly printing non-English characters, for reference, this is my code.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8)
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)

    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfie;
    ZeroMemory(&cfie, sizeof(cfie));
    cfie.cbSize = sizeof(cfie);
    lstrcpyW(cfie.FaceName, L"Lucida Console");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hStdOut, 0, &cfie);
    printf("Ћирилични текст\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This is what the program prints out depending on whether I do or don't define the constant in a command line argument while compiling.

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>gcc test.c

C:\Users\User\Desktop>a.exe
Ћириличан текст

C:\Users\User\Desktop>gcc -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=2 test.c

C:\Users\User\Desktop>a.exe
������������������ ����������
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because outputting to standard output is done literally byte-by-byte when POSIX compliance is in effect.  It uses a different implementation of what is done inside the `printf` function.

Comment: So I have no option other than deleting the macro then?